# Custom taxonomy for product not working

Tags: wordpress, .htaccess, woocommerce

I have created a custom taxonomy for WooCommerce products.

```
function add_hunts_type(){
 // Car Hunts
    $cHunt_labels = array(
        'name'              => __( 'Hunts', 'pixar' ),
        'singular_name'     => __( 'Hunt', 'pixar' ),
        'search_items'      => __( 'Search Hunts', 'pixar' ),
        'all_items'         => __( 'All Hunts', 'pixar' ),
        'parent_item'       => __( 'Parent Hunt', 'pixar' ),
        'parent_item_colon' => __( 'Parent Hunt:', 'pixar' ),
        'edit_item'         => __( 'Edit Hunt', 'pixar' ),
        'update_item'       => __( 'Update Hunt', 'pixar' ),
        'add_new_item'      => __( 'Add New Hunt', 'pixar' ),
        'new_item_name'     => __( 'New Hunt', 'pixar' ),
        'menu_name'         => __( 'Hunts', 'pixar' ),
    );
    $cHunt_args = array(
    'labels' => $cHunt_labels,
    'hierarchical'               => true,
    'public'                     => true,
    'show_ui'                    => true,
    'show_admin_column'          => true,
    'show_in_nav_menus'          => true,
    'show_tagcloud'              => true,
    'query_var' => true,
    'rewrite' => array( 'slug' => 'carhunt' )
    );
    register_taxonomy( 'car_Hunt', 'product', $cHunt_args );
}
add_action( 'init', 'add_hunts_type', 0 );

    /* Flush rewrite rules for custom post types. */
add_action( 'after_switch_theme', 'flush_rewrite_rules' );
```

This is working when I login into admin. When I want to try from the front end it's not working.

- I have change permalinks
- I have deleted `.htaccess` and regenerated  it
- I have other inbuilt things which are working properly

Please let me know if I've missed something.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Register Custom Taxonomy in WooCommerce

add below function in function.php

```
<?php
// Register Custom Taxonomy
function custom_taxonomy_Hunt()  {

    $labels = array(
        'name'                       => 'Hunts',
        'singular_name'              => 'Hunt',
        'menu_name'                  => 'Hunt',
        'all_items'                  => 'All Hunts',
        'parent_item'                => 'Parent Hunt',
        'parent_item_colon'          => 'Parent Hunt:',
        'new_item_name'              => 'New Hunt Name',
        'add_new_item'               => 'Add New Hunt',
        'edit_item'                  => 'Edit Hunt',
        'update_item'                => 'Update Hunt',
        'separate_items_with_commas' => 'Separate Hunt with commas',
        'search_items'               => 'Search Hunts',
        'add_or_remove_items'        => 'Add or remove Hunts',
        'choose_from_most_used'      => 'Choose from the most used Hunts',
    );
    $args = array(
        'labels'                     => $labels,
        'hierarchical'               => true,
        'public'                     => true,
        'show_ui'                    => true,
        'show_admin_column'          => true,
        'show_in_nav_menus'          => true,
        'show_tagcloud'              => true,
        'query_var'                 =>  true,
        'rewrite'                   => array( 'slug' => 'carhunt' )
    );
    register_taxonomy( 'carhunt', 'product', $args );
    register_taxonomy_for_object_type( 'carhunt', 'product' );

}
add_action( 'init', 'custom_taxonomy_Hunt' );
?>
```

Comment: Thank you for help.This work but I forget to put dash in slugname (-).Good going keep it up.Here is lots of to learn.